# What are the differences between ways of instantiating Python objects?

Tags: python-3.x, class, initialization

What is the difference between the following ways of instantiating objects?

```
my_object = my_class()
my_object.function1()
```

and

```
my_class() as my_object:
    my_object.function1()
```

Comment: I believe the `as` keyword is restricted for use in import statements for the purpose of creating an alias.  I don't believe it can be used for object instantiation.